# Template overloading with specialized and unspecialized type

Tags: c++, templates

```
template < typename...dummy >
class wrapper;

template < typename TYPE >
class wrapper < TYPE > {};

template < template < typename... > class TYPE, typename... PARAMS >
class wrapper < TYPE < PARAMS... > > {};

template < typename >
class templated_class {};
class normal_class {};

typedef wrapper < normal_class > normal_wrapper;
typedef wrapper < templated_class, int > templated_wrapper;
```

Compiling the above results obviously in the error

`'templated_class': class template ( not specialized ) cannot be a template argument for 'dummy', an actual type was expected`

How can I make it work so that `wrapper` can accept `normal_class` and `templated_class` as first parameter ? I feel like there is an easy approach, but I dont see it because Im too hung up on the problem.

The reason I cannot just write

```
typedef wrapper < templated_class < int > > templated_wrapper;
```

is because the typedef is created by a variadic macro, which - stripped for MCVE purposes - looks like this:

```
#define first_va(f,...) f
#define createwrapper(...) \
    typedef wrapper < __VA_ARGS__ > first_va(__VA_ARGS__)_wrapper;

createwrapper(normal_class)
createwrapper(templated_class,int)
```

And I have no idea on how to perform the preprocessor wizardry to enclose all parameters after the first in `<>`, if it is even possible.

Solutions using templates or macros are both acceptable for me, although I would prefer a template solution.

Comment: the last typedef needs an extra typename ... at that point templated_class isn't a type (but templated_class<something> is) - so specifying `wrapper<typename templated_class, int>` allows the compiler to not look for `templated_class` immediately..... Oh, and you may need to extend wrapper - `template<typename T, typename U = int> class templated_wrapper : public wrapper<typename T>  {};` as yet another template class

Comment: You cannot overload a class template, only specialize. And when you specialize, you cannot change the kind of temolate argument.

Comment: @Fox `typedef wrapper < typename templated_class, int > templated_wrapper` results in the same error message (visual studio 2013). And I'm not sure what purpose your `templated_wrapper` has in the context of my question.

Comment: Slyps - the basic error is this - you are saying this new class is wrapper<goo, int> without saying what goo is (the compiler has goo and wrapper in its satchel to use when needed on ints and floats, but goo or wrapper by itself not a valid ... or solid... type). What you can do is use SFINAE, or simple class-inheritance instead of typedef. If you say I want to extend goo of somekind into templated_wrapper of somekind, then it knows it is a template.

Comment: @n.m. & Fox: My question was not "why" this error appears, I thought I implied that by saying "**obviously** results in the error"

Comment: I thought the question was "How can I make it work so that wrapper can accept normal_class and templated_class as first parameter?" You cannot have a class template that does that because class templates are not overloadable like that.

Comment: @n.m. Yes, "How" it's possible - in the context of the code provided in my question - to have wrapper accept both `normal_class` and `templated_class`, not specifying a limit of changes of the declaration of `wrapper` or a limit on steps between writing `normal_class/templated_class` in the macro and ultimately having the typedef. My wording on the question you quoted might have been confusing, but T.C. and dyn ( who for some reason deleted his comment ) perfectly understood it, so this question is answered correctly by them.

Comment: They answered something you needed answered, not something you have asked (two different things). Kudos to them. Their solutin overloads on the number of argunents, not their kind, and has other restrictions, but if tghat's what you need...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
#define createwrapper_single(f) \
    typedef wrapper<f> f##_wrapper;
#define createwrapper_multiple(f, ...) \
    typedef wrapper<f<__VA_ARGS__> > f##_wrapper;

#define pick_createwrapper(_1, _2, _3, _4, _5, _6, _7, _8, _9, _10, NAME, ...) NAME
#define createwrapper(...) \
    pick_createwrapper(__VA_ARGS__, createwrapper_multiple, createwrapper_multiple, \
    createwrapper_multiple, createwrapper_multiple, createwrapper_multiple, \
    createwrapper_multiple, createwrapper_multiple, createwrapper_multiple, \
    createwrapper_multiple, createwrapper_single, something_is_wrong_if_this_is_used)(__VA_ARGS__)
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/5f11f30a8ca23507). Obviously as written this will break if you are crazy enough to write a template taking more than 9 parameters, but you can extend it to as many as you want, if necessary.

---

Alternatively, you can use `decltype` and overloading functions:

```
template <template < typename... > class T, typename... params>
wrapper<T<params...>> wrapper_helper();

template <typename T>
wrapper<T> wrapper_helper();

#define first_va(f,...) f
#define PASTE2(x, y) x##y
#define PASTE(x, y) PASTE2(x,y)
#define createwrapper(...) \
    typedef decltype(wrapper_helper< __VA_ARGS__ >()) \
            PASTE(first_va(__VA_ARGS__,_blank), _wrapper);
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e8b97a1dab2fbe03).

Comment: Very nice trick at the macro solution which solved my problem to figure out if there is more than 1 parameter used to write <> or not. With @dyp idea I was in the middle of writing the decltype version, but you were faster. +1

Answer (score 0):

You cannot have that. Once you define a template that has all its parameters of the simple `typename` kind (not templates and not values), all specializations must use types as actual template arguments. Conversely, if the parameter is a template, the corresponding argument will always be a template in any specialization. That is, no overloading for class templates.

You are trying to do the impossible thing because you are confusing two bracket-delimiting list that are present in partial specializations. I think I'll just explain it with code [live demo here](http://ideone.com/RwWOnh).

```
#include <iostream>

template <typename...>            // <--- to instantiate, say `wrapper<whatever list of types>`
struct wrapper
{
  static void foo() {
    std::cout << "generic" << std::endl;
  }
};

template<typename T>
struct wrapper<T>                 // <--- to instantiate, say `wrapper<sometype>`
{
  static void foo() {
    std::cout << "one argument" << std::endl;
  }
};

// just an illustration
template <typename T>              // <--------------------------------------------------+
struct wrapper <int, double, T>    // <--- to instantiate, use this list of arguments    |
{                                  //          not this one -----------------------------+
                                   //          that is, say `wrapper<int, double, sometype>`
                                   //          not `wrapper<sometype>`
  static void foo() {
    std::cout << "three arguments (int, double, something)" << std::endl;
  }
};

template <template<typename ...> class T,   // <-----------------------------------------+
         typename K>               //                                                    |
struct wrapper<T<K>>               // <--- to instantiate, use this list of arguments    |
{                                  //         not this one ------------------------------+
                                   //         that is, say `wrapper<sometemplate<sometype>>`
  static void foo() {
        std::cout << "the template thingy" << std::endl;
  }
};

template <typename> class X {};

int main ()
{
  wrapper<int, int>::foo();
  wrapper<int>::foo();
  wrapper<int, double, X<int>>::foo();
  wrapper<X<int>>::foo();
}
```